error occured after building my project in ROS1 Noetic in Ubuntu 20.04.6
Could NOT find gazebo (missing: gazebo_DIR)
-- Could not find the required component 'gazebo'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/noetic/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
Could not find a package configuration file provided by "gazebo" with any
of the following names:
gazeboConfig.cmake
gazebo-config.cmake

Add the installation prefix of "gazebo" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
"gazebo_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "gazebo"
provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
installed.

Do you have ros-noetic-gazebo-ros installed?
